# I keep getting an error using NEST "Metadata is not of Nested type"

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I enter the below query and the response that is returned is a 400 error saying "Metadata is not of Nested type" can anyone help me with this?

var res = client.Search(s => s.Query(q =>q.Nested(n => n.Path(b => b.Metadata).Query(nq => nq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Metadata.ObjectType).Terms("Doc"))).IgnoreUnmapped())));

Comment: You're using a `nested` query with a document field that is not mapped as a `nested` type; the default Elasticsearch mapping for a C# POCO property that is a POCO is `object`. Take a look at the mapping in the index for the document type in question.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. As mentioned by Russ Cam in the comments the document wasn't stored with a query that specified nesting of objects. I have changed my query to:

var res = client.Search(s => s.Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Metadata.ObjectId).Query("90.en.AU").Operator(Operator.And))));

This worked for me as it treated the Metadata field as a normal field and not a nested field.